Travelling to India with an expired H1B visa (from the US) but have valid Canadian visa. is transit allowed via LHR can anyone sharerecent experience?
I am a citizen of India with normal Indian password
I am travelling from United States on airline British Airways
I am travelling to Mumbai on airline British Airways
I am transiting airport via Heathrow with 3 hour layover
I have the following visa(s) that may be relevant.
Canadian tourist and work Visa
Expired H1 visa

It is a variant but definitely unique situation. If someone who experienced this can answer the question and if we keep them separate would help others in this situation. Its far more specific

A question like yours where the asker comes from any other country would is also more specific, And the asker might come from any of those countries do you think we should have 40000 (200*200) questions just to help people in those situations? (And then I haven't factored in the possible layover locations and all the other facts that might make situations unique, but the answer the same. That is simply not tenable or how duplicates are supposed to work. (I've used 200 because that's around the right figure for the number of countries in the world and made the calculation much easier)

Airline websites have links to check document required, they handle a lot of special cases, and they know about transfer on their airports. Then you may ask here for interpretation, but how can we help? We will use the same sources (because things changes), and doing so we had to do many guesses about you.

The question was for anyone who has experienced this recently.. So if you have not experienced this please move on and refrain from commenting. How big of a deal is that? There is a human on the other side who is genuinely facing an issue and was asking for help and here we are as a community. Wonderful. Thanks for the empathy.

@giacomoCatenazzi. Unfortunately they don't thats why i worded the question so someone can share their personal experience if there was someone like that from the community. However, I get downvoted.

Given the consequences of being denied entry, I don't think anyone's personal experiences are relevant. Either you are eligible according to the rules or you aren't. If the border guard forgot to check the rules one day, it doesn't mean they will for you. The linked answer has a website which shows you the rules; unless it says that expired visas are accepted then you can only assume they are not.

What did your own research on this tell you before you posted your question? Did you check the BA travel document advice page for example?
